# I can connect to my pc over wifi for file sharing, but I cant connect via rdp. Why not?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

One Windows 10 machine, trying to rdp into a windows 8  machine.

On the windows 10 machine, I go to file explorer, click network, my 2nd pc pops up. I can double click it to see the user folder and the desktop files etc. but when I right click on the 2nd pc and click remote desktop it wont connect. It says "remote access is not enabled to the server, the remote computer is turned off, the remote computer is not available on the network"

I went onto the windows 8 machine, pushed windows key + pause. Opened remote settings, "allow remote connections" is enabled. The account on the windows 8 machine is administrator. When I ping the windows 8 machine from my windows 10 machine, I get a response. So I can ping the windows 8 machine from my windows 10 machine, and I can access the files via wifi from my windows 10 machine. I just cant rdp. Why not?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me

Comment: Just checked the firewall. by default theres 4 different entries for port 3389. I enabled all of them. Still wont let me connect

Comment: Can you telnet to port 3389?

Comment: I tried to telnet. It just said "connecting to 12.12.1.132........" then like 4 minutes later it press any key to continue and closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that RDP is not listening on port 3389. Check the following registry key:

```
Start > Run > regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
```

Make sure the key is set to 3389 (decimal)

It's possible that you have a local firewall on that Windows 8 machine that is separate to the built in Windows firewall. Many anti-virus packages like Norton, Trend etc. have firewalls, you may have to allow RDP in this firewall as well.

Try and telnet to 3389 on the Windows 8 machine to make sure the RDP is listening:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3389
```

Try to RDP to another machine from the Windows 10 machine.

Try to RDP to the windows 8 machine from a machine other than the Windows 10 machine.